# Facing Py4JJavaError on executing PySpark Code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

[image]I'm  trying to execute my first PySpark code in PyCharm IDE ,and facing the following exception.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext


def example():
    sc = SparkContext('local')
    words = sc.parallelize(["scala", "java", "hadoop", "spark", "akka"])
    print(sc.getConf().getAll())
    return words.count()


print(example())
```

and Printed the following data.

```
[('spark.master', 'local'), ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'), ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'), ('spark.driver.port', '59627'), ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'), ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'), ('spark.app.id', 'local-1526547201037'), ('spark.driver.host', 'LAPTOP-DDRRK6SB'), ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'), ('spark.app.name', 'pyspark-shell')]
```

and the following exception.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Sorry for my English, Expecting what's wrong with the code.

Comment: which line fails?

Comment: Same works for me

Comment: words.count() for executing this line facing the exception

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: please check now, I have updated with screen shot

Comment: Which Java / JDK version do you use?

Comment: java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Comment: I'd recommend downgrade to Java 8.

Comment: https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SPARK-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exact problem, On rolling back to 1.8.0_171 to this java version, It is working fine. Thanks Rumoku for your suggestion.